# ¿Como asignarle teclas para que se mueva mi cuadrado en PyGame? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Soy nuevo en PyGame y estoy intentando hacer que un cuadrado que dibujé se mueva, a la izquierda o a la derecha. Use el evento `KEYDOWN` con la asignación de teclas `K_LEFT` y `K_RIGHT`. Esto dentro de un condicional, dentro del bucle principal del juego:

```
while not end:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

        if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
            if event.type == pg.K_LEFT:
                x_pos = x_pos - 30
            elif event.type == pg.K_RIGHT:
                x_pos = x_pos + 30
```

**Nota:** `pg` es `pygame`, lo decidí importar de esa forma.

Por lo que entiendo si este condicional que involucra las teclas va antes de cuando se dibuja el rectángulo (en este caso cuadrado), el cuadrado se tendría de que dibujar de diferente forma, o bien desplazarse.

Cuando ejecuto, aparece el cuadrado dibujado en las coordenadas que indiqué, con el fondo del color que le indiqué, pero al presionar las teclas no pasa nada. En el [tutorial que estoy siguiendo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-8n91btt5d8), el lo hace de esta manera y le funciona. Sinceramente no sé que estoy haciendo mal, de seguro es una tontería muy pequeña.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi pregunta es: **¿De qué manera puede hacer lo que quiero, que el cuadrado se mueva dependiendo de la tecla que presiono?** Finalmente adjunto mi código completo, para que se entienda el contexto de las variables, entre otras cosas.

```
import sys
import pygame as pg

pg.init()

rHeight = 700
rWidth = 550

whiteC = (255,255,255)
baseC = (73,0,230)

x_pos = 332.5
y_pos = 500

screen = pg.display.set_mode((rHeight,rWidth))

end = False

while not end:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

        if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
            if event.type == pg.K_LEFT:
                x_pos = x_pos - 30
            elif event.type == pg.K_RIGHT:
                x_pos = x_pos + 30


    screen.fill(whiteC)
    pg.draw.rect(screen,baseC,(x_pos,y_pos,35,35))
    pg.display.update()
```

Agradecería mucho cualquier ayuda, un gran saludo!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Básicamente modificando esto debería andar:

```
if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
    if event.key == pg.K_LEFT:
        x_pos = x_pos - 30
    if event.key == pg.K_RIGHT:
        x_pos = x_pos + 30
```

Comment: A lo mejor deberías indicar que cambiaste `event.type` por `event.key`, me costó notarlo jaja